# How to debug C application using eclipse IDE under Linux

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

As you know,eclipse IDE has a convenient **attached debugging facility** for C project.You can see it from the [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hJYH.png) and you can use this facility to debug process that are already in running status,like **daemon process**..

**My question** is that when a process just started and I want to debug it from the begining of the process(i.e. from the first line of main function),how I can do it using the IDE?

I know under **Windows**,there is a tool called **gflag**,using this tool we can do some configuraitons before starting the process,and when the process is launched,the gflag can detect this and let the debugger tool(e.g. virtual studio) attach the process automatically.

Do not tell me that use **sleep** fuction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check CDT reverse debugging. You will need GDB 7.0 or later for this feature.

Refer
[How_do_I_do_Reverse_Debugging](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_do_Reverse_Debugging.3F)

Answer (score 0):

Open source code with eclipse and double click the left of line number to add a break point. Then you can create a session to debug your application

Comment: Sorry,but you don't  answer my question.

Comment: @HarlanChen I think launching the process manually is just the same as attaching it automatically when it is launched. So what configurations do you set before debugging your app?